# Handling Multiple Views/ Multiple Urls in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm having the 404 error when trying to handle a view that is not related to the main page. For example, if I initially start at the main page *home*, and want to navigate to another page called, *otherpage*, I receive a 404 otherpage.html not found.

The way I'm doing is based off intuition. So if there's a better way to do this, please mention it:

in the file:

```
prd/
   views.py
   url.py
   otherstuffthatshouldbehere.py..
```

I have **views.py** (this is where I think the error is):

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    context = {}
    template = "index.html"
    return render(request, template, context)

def otherpage(request):
    context = {}
    template = "otherpage.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Then urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'prd.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^$', 'prd.views.otherpage', name='otherpage'),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

This returns a 404 for the otherpage.html. I have the template directory working fine. But how do I go about handling multiple views?

EDIT:

Upon adding:

```
url(r'^otherpage$', 'prd.views.otherpage', name='otherpage'),
```

I received this error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in prd.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^$ [name='home']
^about$ [name='about']
^projects$ [name='projects']
^admin/
The current URL, about.html, didn't match any of these.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `urlpatterns` starts at the top and then goes down until it matches a URL based on the regex. In order for Django to serve up the page located at otherpage.html there has to be a URL defined in urlpatterns that matches otherpage.html otherwise you will get the 404.

In this case you have:

```
url(r'^$', 'prd.views.home', name='home'),
url(r'^$', 'prd.views.otherpage', name='otherpage'),
```

Note that nothing will ever get to `otherpage` here because `home` has the same pattern (regex) and will therefore always match first. You want to have a different URL for both those so that you can differentiate between them. Perhaps you could do something like:

```
url(r'^$', 'prd.views.home', name='home'),
url(r'^otherpage.html$', 'prd.views.otherpage', name='otherpage'),
```

After making this change you now have a match for otherpage and hopefully no more 404.

EDIT:

```
url(r'^otherpage.html$', 'prd.views.otherpage', name='otherpage'),
```

This matches `www.example.com/otherpage.html` but it will not match `www.example.com/otherpage`

To match `www.example.com/otherpage` you need to use:

```
url(r'^otherpage$', 'prd.views.otherpage', name='otherpage'),
```

Note the difference in the regex, there's no `.html` here. The regex matches exactly what you put in it.

Comment: Oh that's neat. But now I have the error of Using the URLconf defined in project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns. (I'll add to the main question)

Comment: @WillCampbell I made an edit that hopefully explains the cause of that issue.

Comment: Awesome, that helped immensely. Thanks!